# iOS: UIApplicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification

Tags: ios, class, uiviewcontroller, delegates, instance

Is there anything like this outside of the application delegate? I would just like to be able to do certain things in my view controllers when I receive a notification. Will I just have to import each of them and check the type of class against my current view controllers in order to perform actions on them?

Essentially, if I received a remote notification and I didn't have an exact reference to the top most view controller on the stack, is there a good way to access a class or instance method of that controller? Or maybe even some properties?

Comment: It's only in the app delegate. Why not just make a property for the view controllers you might need to access and refer to those when you need to do something with them.

Comment: A property where? Each referring to a viewController? That would become way too heavy if they were retained. The answer is very light weight, but I was thinking along this approach as a fall back.

Comment: It will not be heavy at all if those view controllers exist through the app lifecycle anyway. All you will have is some extra pointers to already existing things. You can make them weak properties if you don't want to retain them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just send an NSNotification (don't mistake **notification center** and **Apple Push Notifications**) to them? You have a nice article [here](http://devinsheaven.com/cocoa-tutorial-passing-messages-between-objects-notifications-delegates-and-target-action/) talking about it.

Comment: Wow. I definitely overlooked the notification center. I'm still really new to iOS, but I thought it was strictly set for built in notifications and you couldn't push your own. I think this will make a huge impact on a lot of what I've done so far. This is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Also, what is good practice for keeping a certain notification on the top most viewController? Adding the observer with viewWillAppear: and removing it on viewWillDisappear:?

Comment: viewDidLoad, ideally (if a view controller should continue listening after its view is off screen). The Appear/Disappear functions will get called multiple times (any time you navigate to/from a view).

Comment: One caveat about `-viewDidLoad` is that you may not be able to use `-viewDidUnload` in the future. The right place to do this depends on what you are doing. What does your view controller want to do in response to the event?

Comment: Well, I said that I don't want them listening off screen, so wouldn't that mean that viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear are the best options?